# how to modify day which is inside a date string

Tags: python

i have seen some threats about this already but im not quite sure how to do mine. i have a string date (DD/MM/YY) then i need to subtract the day by 2 and i need to change it to (MM/DD/YY). For example, if i have a string of 01/04/2021, i need the final output to be 03/30/2021. i have tried using datetime.date but it seems like i cannot put a string of 01/04/2021 in it. Any helps? Here is what i got so far, but it doesn't really work i don't quite understand datetime library so its a little bit confusing, sorry in advance.

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date_1 = '01/04/2021'
date_2 = list(date_1)
date_2[0:2], date_2[3:5] = date_2[3:5], date_2[0:2] 
date_2 = ''.join(date_2) # change date_1 to MM/DD/YY 
print(dt.date(int(date_2[0:4]),int(date_2[5:7]), int(date_2[8:10])) - relativedelta(days=2)) # i tried to minus the day out, but the code fails, 
#Here is the error, in case it helps, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '04/0'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `timedelta`, `strptime` and `strftime`.

```
from datetime import datetime    
from datetime import timedelta
d = '01/04/2021'

print((datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y') - timedelta(days=2)).strftime('%m/%d/%y'))
#03/30/21
```

---

**Explanation**

`datetime.strptime`: This function allows you to take a `string`, provide the formatting and return a `datetime` object.

```
datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y')
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0)
```

`datetime.timedelta`: Allows us to add and subtract time on a `datetime` object.

```
datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y') - timedelta(days=2)
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 30, 0, 0)
```

`datetime.strftime`: Allows us to format our datetime object as a `string` in the format we specify

```
datetime(2021, 3, 30, 0, 0).strftime('%m/%d/%y')
'03/30/21'
```

Joining these all together, we can convert your `string` to a `date`, make the change to the `date` that we want, and then convert it back to a `string`.

Comment: hi sorry i implemented ur code in and i just realised that your code took out 20 in front of the year. I need that so it makes 4digit in the year. Any way around it? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes. `strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`